# Define HTML class to represent multiple HTML classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to front-end development; I'd like to define a class in my HTML document that encapsulates multiple HTML classes.

For example, below, I have a header and a set of other elements that have the same list of classes applied to them. If I ever change one, though, I'll have to remember to change the other, and if I keep adding more special types of elements that I want styled the same way, I'll have to update each of them every time.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="sortTrue1" class="list-group">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="list-group-item col-md-4"> <!-- This guy -->
           ...
        </div>
     </div>
     {% for name in names1 %}
       <div class="row">
         <div class="list-group-item col-md-4"> <!-- And this guy -->
           ...
         </div>
       </div>
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to define a class `x` such that `<div class=x>...</div>` will apply multiple classes?

Comment: Why don't you try to re-group your classes in a more efficient way then use multiple classes on elements...

Comment: You can achieve this easily using a template engine such as [erb partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) ... you can define the div as a partial and update code once use it anywhere...some front end templating engines include [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) ,  [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) , and [Angular.js templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)

Comment: Not with CSS. You can achieve that using tools like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Templating makes a lot of sense. I'm using Jinja2/Flask, it didn't occur to me that I could use that.

Comment: sure there is. you can add ".x " in front of the other rules you wish to bundle, or better, use ".x" to hit the "root" of the repetition and use relative selectors from the root to define your rules. for a frameworks like BS, that's going to be pretty involved if you want to re-implement all the built-ins, but for modifying an existing set of customization, it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this like you've asked for, but I think it would work with this:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (var i = 0; i<matches.length; i++)
{
    if (matches[i].className == 'x')
    {
        matches[i].className = 'all the classes you want'
    }
}
```